# KmyMoney Online Quote for AMFI

Tags: regex

AMFI publishes price in CSV format with ";" as delimiter.  This is published in url https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt

The contents are like the following

Aditya Birla Sun Life Mutual Fund

119551;INF209KA12Z1;INF209KA13Z9;Aditya Birla Sun Life Banking & PSU Debt Fund  - Direct Plan-Dividend;154.7628;03-Jul-2020
119552;INF209K01YM2;-;Aditya Birla Sun Life Banking & PSU Debt Fund - Direct Plan-Monthly Dividend;114.3133;03-Jul-2020
119553;INF209K01YO8;-;Aditya Birla Sun Life Banking & PSU Debt Fund - Direct Plan-Quarterly Dividend;111.6641;03-Jul-2020
108272;INF209K01LX6;INF209KA11Z3;Aditya Birla Sun Life Banking & PSU Debt Fund - Regular Plan-Dividend;161.8902;03-Jul-2020
108273;INF209K01LV0;-;Aditya Birla Sun Life Banking & PSU Debt Fund - Regular Plan-Growth;273.2973;03-Jul-2020

I have configured Online quotes as follows:

URL: https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt
CSV URL: https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt
Identifier: %1
Identified by : Symbol
Price: ^((.+?);){5}
Date: \d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}$
Date Format: %d %m %y
[image: configure KmyMoney]

The definition of the security is as follows:
Trading Symbol: 119550
Full Name: Aditya Birla Sun Life Banking & PSU Debt Fund- Direct Plan-Growth
Fraction: 1000
Trading Market: Fund
Identification Number: 119550
Trading currency: Indian rupee
Price entry: Default
Price Precision: 4

[image: Investment detail wizard page 1]
[image: Investment detail wizard page 2]

When price update is initiated getting following error:

[image: Price Update]

The regex placed in https://regex101.com/ returned values correctly. Please help correct the regex to resolve the issue.

Comment: What is your expected result?Please can you add that?

Comment: For the line if selected 

119550;INF209K01YN0;-;Aditya Birla Sun Life Banking & PSU Debt Fund- Direct Plan-Growth;278.8384;03-Jul-2020

Price column should get 5th column, and last update date as 6th column.  In the above example Price=278.8384 and last update date 03-Jul-2020

Comment: Try `(?m)^(?:(.*?);){5}` for price and `(?m)\b\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}$` for date

Comment: This is not working, getting same error.  I think the program expects the data in one line, but this link gets a file.  When it try to look in the first line, there is no data.  Can we regex and get a single line out of a file/url?